# Getting a value from a different row

Tags: sql

Our users are billed monthly, quarterly and annually. I have a table which looks at their next billing date and sums the amounts. This creates a slight issue if we want to look more than a month ahead in time as dates only see the monthly invoice amount and won't be present in a 2 month or more view.

Current table:

```
+------------+---------------+-----------------+
| Date       | Total Billing | Monthly Portion |
+------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 11/03/2021 | 10000.00      | 140.00          |
+------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 12/03/2021 | 10350.00      | 610.00          |
+------------+---------------+-----------------+
| ...        | ...           | ...             |
+------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 11/04/2021 | 12080.00      | 0               |
+------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 12/04/2021 | 15020.00      | 0               |
+------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

What i'd like to achieve:

```
+------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Date       | Total Billing | Monthly Portion | Transfer Monthly Portion from Previous Month |
+------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------+
| 11/03/2021 | 10000.00      | 140.00          | 0                                            |
+------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------+
| 12/03/2021 | 10350.00      | 610.00          | 0                                            |
+------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------+
| ...        | ...           | ...             | ...                                          |
+------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------+
| 11/04/2021 | 12080.00      | 0               | 140.00                                       |
+------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------+
| 12/04/2021 | 15020.00      | 0               | 610.00                                       |
+------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Basically 1 month later copy over the 'monthly portion' cell.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your question and your sample data are not in synch, because the question references looking more than one month in the future.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the sample data is just a demonstration of what the table looks like. I think it should be quite clear from it. `Monthly Portion` to be put in column `Transfer Monthly` but 1 month forward.

Comment: In this sample data the only way to know whether It's same bill in different month is total bill column. It should not be. Please mention the column name to identify any bill uniquely.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur isn't that the purpose of the `date` column?

Comment: .You can have two or more bill in a date right?  then how will you know which previous amount yoy need to show. Isn’t there any bill no or ref no type column?

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur this is total billing for the date. each date is unique so you cant have more than 1.

Comment: ok then you need to show the previous month's bill of same day

Comment: which dbms you are using?

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur MySQL, so your Lag() suggestion is a good idea.

Comment: That's great. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lag partition by day(date) to find previous bill of same day?

```
select date,  totalbilling,  monthlyporrtion, lag(monthlyportiin) over (patition by day(date) order by date) traansfermonthlyportion
from currenttable
```

Do you generate bill at 29,30 or 31th day of month? Those can cause mismatch in days with previous month.

Comment: the bills are already generated looking forward - we know on March 15 we will bill X amount. But yes, we run into the problem of having a bill in March 31, but there is no April 31 (in those cases it will need to be assigned to April 30)

Comment: But in next year in march you would have problem for 29,30 and 31. How you are planning to address that. If possible then you should try to generate bills from 1 to 28th of any month only.